# Getting values in choice column after list is migrated

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I am working on migrating a list from SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2013.
In SharePoint 2010 list, If a field is choice column then after migrating it to SharePoint 2013, I am not able to get the options in that choice column.

```
Country is choice column
```

[image]
[image]

```
 if (field.FieldTypeKind.ToString() == "Choice")
                                {
                                    string fieldSchema = "<Field Type='" + field.FieldTypeKind + "' DisplayName='" + field.Title + "' Name='" + field.InternalName + "' Hidden='" + field.Hidden + "' Format='Dropdown'><CHOICES></CHOICES></Field>";

                                    targetcollField.AddFieldAsXml(fieldSchema, true, AddFieldOptions.AddToDefaultContentType);
                                    targetContext.Load(targetcollField);
                                    srcFieldCollections.Add(field);
                                }
```

I can add the static values in fieldSchema but in my case there are many lists so I need to get it dynamically.

Comment: Do you want to get choices from `field`?

Comment: yes I need to get it from list of SP2010 and set it to list of sp2013

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try following. Approach is get choices from `field` and then set it in field **XML**.

```
 if (field.FieldTypeKind.ToString() == "Choice") {

        var choices = new List < string > ();
        FieldChoice country = (FieldChoice) field;

        for (int i = 0; i < country.Choices.Count; i++) {
            var choice = string.Format("<CHOICE>{0}</CHOICE>", country.Choices[i]);
            choices.Add(choice);
        }
        string fieldSchema = "<Field Type='" + field.FieldTypeKind + "' DisplayName='" + field.Title + "' Name='" + field.InternalName + "' Hidden='" + field.Hidden + "' Format='Dropdown'><CHOICES>" + string.Join("", choices) + "</CHOICES></Field>";

        targetcollField.AddFieldAsXml(fieldSchema, true, AddFieldOptions.AddToDefaultContentType);
        targetContext.Load(targetcollField);
        srcFieldCollections.Add(field);
    }
```

Comment: Showing error for this line `SPFieldChoice country = (SPFieldChoice) field`;
`Cannot convert type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Field' to 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldChoice'`

Comment: Use `FieldChoice` instead of `SPFieldChoice` in case of `'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Field'`

Comment: Yes, I have used the same and also the choices was showing empty so I changed it with choice variable in xml and now everything is working fine.
Thanks

Comment: Opps. forgot `choices.Add(choice);`. Answer updated. Now you can accept.